# After downloading Adobe/Acrobat, internal storage is filled with 100's of thumbnails to gallery?

Tags: images, google-photos, adobe-reader

For professional reasons, I needed to download Adobe/Acrobat on Android. Shortly, I noticed my Google Photos and Google Drive had 100+ thumbnail clipart replacing all my media, as well as internal storage, which is a lot of space, with my 64 GB SD card, which is suddenly empty.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| Gallery showing at least 500 of these thumbnails | More Info option, description |

I have always moved what my phone will allow to SD or other external devices.

What did Adobe/Acrobat do to my phone? I have uninstalled it, but I still can't find the important files on my device.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Those images are image resources contained in the APK of Adobe Reader. Have you checked the `/Download` folder whether there is a `/AdobeReader...` folder? I have a hunch that the APK was accidentally extracted there, considering that APK is also a ZIP file, and thus Google Photos detected the images and showed them in the app.

Comment: Your second screen shot shows that your gallery app seems to detect thumbnails which are located in the downloaded Adobe Reader APK file (which is no longer necessary after installation). Thus your gallery seems to be capable of finding images within ZIP files. Therefore I would start by deleting `AdobeReader-arm64-v8a-release.apk` from your Download folder.